# page.replace_html method in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my code in  client/orders controller.

```
render :update do |page|
            page.replace_html "example_check" ,:partial=>'customer/orders/pending_orders',:object=> "Your Message Has Been Sent "
        end
```

In customer/orders/pending_orders.html.erb

```
<div id="example_check">replace here</div>
```

I want to replace `"Your Message Has Been Sent "`message in another controller view file called `'customer/orders/pending_orders'`. The  replacement working fine for same controller.Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
 page.replace_html "example_check", "Your Message Has Been Sent"
```