# ajax request in rails 2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
function ajaxRequest(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'client/orders/send_mail_to_notaries',
        data: { subject: "hi" }
    });
    return false;

  }
```

It doesn't pass any params in controller.Can any one trigger this out?

Comment: Check the console for errors.  Are you adding the required JavaScript files?

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say?
Any errors?

Comment: No.Console  doesn't shows any error.

Comment: Show more information for us to see where the problem is, the code posted is not enough.  Take us through the request from the beginning.  Also, make sure to restart the server after updating the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the question that you have asked today morning [page.replace_html method in rails 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803749/page-replace-html-method-in-rails-2/15804232#15804232) i guess you are using prototype.

Can you check if jQuery is included? Unless jQuery is included this ajax request will not work.

Comment: Yes i couldn't add.How can i add this rails 2.As i am new to this version i can't find solution.

Comment: You can use this jQuery http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js ., I would recommend to get rid of Prototype and use jQuery. If you want to use both jQuery and prototype you can use jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: Thanks alot.Its help me to find solution.

Comment: Your suggestion makes my codes run.Thank you so much.I like to add +5.Unfortunately i can't.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the method you're using and it worked for me. Perhaps there's a problem with the router/controller?

When debugging ajax it's very handy to use the Chrome developer toolbar.  Bring it up, run the javascript and see what happens.

To see the response from the server you can then flip to the Network tab to see what the response is.